# How to install DNS over TLS profile in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I have been using Ahadns for quite some time now and on Android I set my private DNS to **dot.in.ahadns.net** simply and it works. Can anyone guide me on how to apply this DNS on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation? I am quite new to these stuff and would like to simply use this dns as a common user for enjoying its ad blocking and good ping.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the `/etc/network/interfaces` file (e.g., `sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces`). There should be a line at the end that says `dns-nameservers X.X.X.X`. Replace `X.X.X.X` with the IP address of your DNS server (to find that, run `dig dot.in.ahadns.net`, and in the `ANSWER SECTION`, there will be an IP address).

So, if the IP address for your chosen DNS server is 8.8.8.8, you would modify the `dns-nameservers` line to say `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`. Of course, substitute the correct IP address.

Reboot your computer, and it should work.